# Let $G = \langle a,b: a^6=b^3 =e , b^{-1}a b =a^3 \rangle$ How many elements does $G$ have? To what family of groups is $G$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G = \langle a,b: a^6=b^3 =e , b^{-1}a b =a^3 \rangle$

How many elements does $G$ have?

To what family of groups is $G$ isomorphic to?

---

**Excersise solutions help**

the given relations implies that $a^2=e$

$$ G \cong \mathbb Z_{6}$$

---

**scratch work**

I am trying to set $g \in G$ as $g=a^i b^j$ and then look at what happens

for powers of $b$ alone

$$\begin{aligned}
b^1=b^1
\\b^2=b^2
\\b^3=e
\end{aligned} $$

for power of a alone
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^1&=a^1
\\a^2 &=a^2 
\\a^3&= b^{-1}a b
\\a^4 &= a^3 * a = b^{-1}a b
\\ a^5 &= a^3 a^2 = (b^-1 a b ) a^2
\\ a^6 &= (b^{-1} a b)(b^{-1}a b )= b^{-1} a b =e \Leftrightarrow a^2=e
\end{aligned}
$$

so there is nothing bigger thatn $a^2$ and nothing bigger than $b^3$

from there the possible elements are

$$ a^1 , b^1 , b^2 , a^1b^1, a^1b^2 ,e$$

---

**Need to argument for** $G \cong Z_6$

---

what I am really tring to do is to warm up to make an argument that Diclycic group has $4n$ elements.  that is another question

Comment: Can you prove that $ab=ba$?

Comment: given $b^{-1} a b = e$ we have that $ab = b$ thus $a = e$ then $ab = ba$

Comment: We can have $a=e$.

Comment: How is $ab=b,$ @MarineGalantin?

Comment: just compose by $b$ on the left, isn't this right?

Comment: On the left of what? @MarineGalantin

Comment: read the third comment again please :)

Comment: How do we have $b^{-1}ab=e$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a^2=e$, you get that $bab^{-1}=a^3=a^2\cdot a=a,$ hence $ba=ab.$

So $$G\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2=e,b^3=e, ab=ba\rangle$$

So this group is $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\cong \mathbb Z_{6}$ by the general rule:

> If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\mathbb Z_{m}\times\mathbb Z_{n}\cong \mathbb Z_{mn}.$

which is essentially the Chinese remainder theorem.

---

Or you can skip that general theorem and just prove that $ab$ is a generator. We have $$\begin{align}(ab)^1&=ab\\(ab)^2&=b^2\\(ab)^3&=a\\(ab)^4&=b\\(ab)^5&=ab^2\\(ab)^6&=e\end{align}$$

---

Or just use that there are two groups of order $6$, $\mathbb Z_6$ and $S_3,$ but $S_3$ is non-abelian.

---

Or you can find an explicit isomorphism: $G\to\mathbb Z_6$ with $a\mapsto 3$ and $b\mapsto 2.$ Since they have the same size, and this is onto, it must also be one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

$b^{-1}a b =a^3$ implies $o(a)=o(a^3)$.

- $o(a)=6 \implies o(a^3)=2$, contradicts $o(a)=o(a^3)$
- $o(a)=3 \implies o(a^3)=1$, contradicts $o(a)=o(a^3)$

Therefore $o(a)=1$ or $o(a)=2$.

- $o(a)=1 \implies G = \langle b: b^3 =e\rangle \cong C_3$.
- $o(a)=2 \implies ab=ba \implies o(ab)=6 \implies G \cong C_6$

Comment: You mean "... or $\sigma(a)=2,$" right?

Comment: The point is, this is a group presentation. This question does not have multiple answers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you're right of course. If this is a group presentation, then you can't deduce that $o(a)=1$ and so $o(a)=2$. MY reading was the $G$ was generated by $a,b$ subject to the relations given, a subtle difference.